# Write a compressing util for gzip files

Tags: code-golf, compression

The task of this challenge is as following:

Write a program that reads a file of reasonable size (let's say <16 MB) from stdin or anywhere else (however you like, but must not be hardcoded), and put's the compressed output onto stdout. The output must be a valid gzip compressed file and if the compressed file runs through gunzip, it should yield exactly the same file as before.

### Rules

- The programming language used must be known *before* this competition started
- The score of your program is the number of characters of the source code or the assembled program (whatever is shorter)
- You're not allowed to use any kind of existing compression libraries.
- Have fun!

Comment: Is the use of built-in libraries allowed?

Comment: @hallvabo: Nope. Forgot this. Thx

Comment: Probably the best way to do this is just to pad the input with the "the following block is uncompressed" markers at the start of every block.

Comment: gzip is a programming language. Not a Turing complete one though.

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the [Guns and Zips](http://codegolf.com/guns-and-zips) problem. Why anyone would post their answers here rather than at codegolf.com is beyond me, unless they want to solve it in a language not supported by codegolf.com (e.g., GolfScript).

Comment: The difference is, that they expect a rather complete implementation of gzip there. In my excercise you may try to cheat instead, as decompression isn't needed.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what constitutes a "valid gzipped file"?  100% RFC compliant?  Whatever goes through gunzip unharmed?

Comment: @J B: Your second choice is right. A valid gzipped representation of a file f is any file g that is equal to f if passed through gunzip.

Comment: Pushing the boundaries even further... is `zcat` (`gzip -cd`) enough?  IOW, how many warnings/errors are we allowed at decompression time?

Comment: J B: I only count what goes to `stdout`. Warnings aren't important in codegolf.

Comment: @FUZxxl: what I mean is: I've got a file that's not valid enough for `gunzip` with no arguments.  But if you get it through `zcat 2>/dev/null`, you *do* get the uncompressed contents back.  Is that good enough?

Comment: 9 bytes: `gzip -c -`. **I** didn't use any compression libraries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## C# (534 characters)

```
using System.IO;using B=System.Byte;class X{static void Main(string[]a){var f=File.ReadAllBytes(a[0]);int l=f.Length,i=0,j;var p=new uint[256];for(uint k=0,r=0;k<256;r=++k){for(j=0;j<8;j++)r=r>>1^(r&1)*0xedb88320;p[k]=r;}uint c=~(uint)0,n=c;using(var o=File.Open(a[0]+".gz",FileMode.Create)){o.Write(new B[]{31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,11},0,10);for(;i<l;i++){o.Write(new B[]{(B)(i<l-1?0:1),1,0,254,255,f[i]},0,6);c=p[(c^f[i])&0xFF]^c>>8;}c^=n;o.Write(new[]{(B)c,(B)(c>>8),(B)(c>>16),(B)(c>>24),(B)l,(B)(l>>8),(B)(l>>16),(B)(l>>24)},0,8);}}}
```

#### Much more readable:

```
using System.IO;
using B = System.Byte;
class X
{
    static void Main(string[] a)
    {
        // Read file contents
        var f = File.ReadAllBytes(a[0]);
        int l = f.Length, i = 0, j;

        // Initialise table for CRC hashsum
        var p = new uint[256];
        for (uint k = 0, r = 0; k < 256; r = ++k)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                r = r >> 1 ^ (r & 1) * 0xedb88320;
            p[k] = r;
        }

        uint c = ~(uint) 0, n = c;

        // Write the output file
        using (var o = File.Open(a[0] + ".gz", FileMode.Create))
        {
            // gzip header
            o.Write(new B[] { 31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 11 }, 0, 10);
            for (; i < l; i++)
            {
                // deflate block header plus one byte of payload
                o.Write(new B[] { (B) (i < l - 1 ? 0 : 1), 1, 0, 254, 255, f[i] }, 0, 6);
                // Compute CRC checksum
                c = p[(c ^ f[i]) & 0xFF] ^ c >> 8;
            }
            c ^= n;
            o.Write(new[] {
                // CRC checksum
                (B) c, (B) (c >> 8), (B) (c >> 16), (B) (c >> 24),
                // original file size
                (B) l, (B) (l >> 8), (B) (l >> 16), (B) (l >> 24)
            }, 0, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Comments:

- Expects path to file as first command-line argument.
- Output file is input file + `.gz`.
- I am not using any libraries to do the gzip, deflate or CRC32. It’s all in there.
- This “compressor” increases the filesize by a factor of 6. But it’s in valid gzip format!
- Tested using GNU gunzip and WinRAR.